# Index with JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have the following select in my application:

```
SELECT psd.type, count(*) as total
FROM question_answer_nps qan
JOIN question_answer qa ON
    qan.question_answer_id = qa.id
JOIN post_sale_action psa ON
    psa.id = qa.post_sale_action_id
JOIN post_sale_dispatch psd ON
    psd.id = psa.post_sale_dispatch_id
JOIN post_sale_lot psl ON
    psl.id = psd.post_sale_lot_id
WHERE qan.nps_answer is not null
    AND psd.status != 0
    AND psa.status in (2, 3)
    AND psl.status != 0
GROUP BY psd.type
```

All joins happen with FK (of course). But I can not form an index to optimize this query.

The explain this select can be viewed at: https://mariadb.org/explain_analyzer/analyze/5mhc6

What would be the index for this select?

Comment: Is there an index on the status field on the post_sale_action table?

Comment: Yes! `INDEX idx_psa_teste (status)`

Comment: How many records on that table have a matching status?

Comment: 380k from 427k records

Comment: Suspect that is why it is ignoring it. The index doesn't narrow the number of records down sufficiently to be worthwhile using. My rough rule of thumb with MySQL is that the index is ignored if  the index doesn't narrow the records selected down below 30%. As such not sure you can improve the index for this query as you are processing 90% of the records. Pity it will still likely appear in any slow query log.

Comment: Query optimizer should in most cases work really good with foreign keys. From my experience it uses full table scans when you use the IN statement. Also move the corresponding expressions in the where clause at the end to the corresponding ON clauses thereby not first retrieving everything first and then filter on it. If this still doesn't help, send us the queryplan so we can figure out what steps the query resolver takes.